# Can i use different admob account in same published app on google play (which uses another admob)

Tags: google-play, admob, game-development, google-play-console

Me and my friend make android games and have published several games on google play. Those games use my friend's admob account for earnings (linked to the game on google play).
But now i want to use my own admob account.
So my question is can i simply remove the app id of my friend's admob account and replace it by my own. And update the game on same play developer account.

Or is this a violation, that i'm using two admob accounts in one google play developer account. But the second account is now mine (not even got suspended)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Simply change application id and ad ids and upload new release build. Do not forgot to update appads.txt location on play store developer dashboard to the place that you published appads.txt of new account.

Comment: Hello Seymur.Is it possible to do that for banned admob account?I mean after admob bans my account can I open new account and link it to my app?